# Add Async/Await to React Fetch Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm making a fetch request to this API and I'm successfully getting the data and printing it to the console. However I'm new to asynchronous calls in Javascript/React. How do add async/await in this code to delay the render upon successful fetch? I'm getting the classic `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` because I believe that the DOM is trying to render the data that hasn't been fully fetched yet.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function News() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [stories, setStory] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "http://api.mediastack.com/v1/news"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setStory(result);
          console.log(result.data[0]);       // printing to console to test response
          console.log(result.data[0].title); // printing to console to test response
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{stories.data[0].title} </p> // this is the where render error is
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sending the API access key?

Comment: yes i am, but I deleted it for this post because it's private to me. isn't that best practice? not to share those sorts of things publicly?

Comment: Maybe you can make your function async and then call it with await.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm asking help with. I know I need async/await but haven't been able to implement it correctly.

Comment: can you show how `result` looks like? (based on the error that is where the code is failing)

Comment: You cannot expect `useEffect` to return information *now* that is only available in the *future*. This can never work.

Comment: try to put `setStory(result);` before `setIsLoaded(true);`

Comment: whoa, i think that worked @zb22. That seems so obvious now!

Comment: State updates are asynchronous and swapping the order of those two lines to fix this issue is a temporary fix. Under different circumstances it may misfire again. Just FYI.

Comment: thanks @codemonkey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `isLoaded` state variable is updated BEFORE `stories`, despite the fact you set the former state first. Here is how to fix this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [stories, setStory] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("your_url")
      .then((res) => return res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setStory(result);
        console.log("Success ", result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!stories) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>stories.data[0].title} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Get rid of the `isLoaded` var altogether and use the `stories` var to indicate that it's being loaded.

If you want to add artificial load time to your api call. You can do something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("your_url")
      .then((res) => return res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setTimeout(() => setStory(result), 2000)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }, []);
```

This will add 2 seconds before setting your state thus letting you see what your loader looks like.

Answer (score 1):

async/await is just another form to retrieve asynchronous data, like you are doing with then.

The message:

```
 Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

means that 'result.data' is undefined.

Anyway, if it entered the "then" callback it always means that the request was fetched, there is no such thing as "half fetched" or "fully fetched".

I suggest you to use the debugger, by placing

```
debugger;
```

right in the beginning of the 'then' callback to ensure what your result is.
or you may also console.log the result.

Just to clarify:

```
myFunctionThatReturnsPromise.then(response => //do something with response)
```

is the same as

```
await response = myFunctionThatReturnsPromise;
```

You might consider using  `stories?.data?.[0]?.title` to fix this problem.

Comment: I know it's fetched the data because it appears in my console. However, I need help writing the async/await part because it's trying to render the <p> tag with data that's not there yet.

Comment: maybe if you use the question mark operator, like: stories?.data?.[0]?.title

Answer (score 0):

your error will not be gone with async await because you are calling a nested empty object which has no value. render method in react is prior to the useEffect you have used. you can approach two solutins:

**1.use optional chaining es20 feature like this:**

```js
<p>{stories?.data?.[0]?.title} </p>
```

**2.use nested if statement before the p tag to check whether it has data or not:**

it seems the first option is much cleaner

Answer (score -1):

You already have async code using `Promise.then` so `async/await` will not help you here - it's just a different way of writing Promise-based functionality.

Your problem is just as you say - React is trying to render your `else` block before `stories` has anything for you to render. I think you just need to write stricter conditions, e.g.

```
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  if (!isLoaded || !stories.data.length) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{stories.data[0].title} </p> // this is the where render error is
    </div>
  );
```